# Extract values > 1.00 from database

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I am very new to SQL;  I am struggling with extracting data from a database. I am trying to extract all records with Au Values > 1.00. 
The AttributeValue column is `NVARCHAR`

This is what I have tried:

```
SELECT TOP 1000 [Id]
      ,[DHGeochemistryId]
      ,[AttributeColumn]
      ,[AttributeValue]
      ,[ModifiedDate]
      ,[ModifiedBy]
      ,[MRTDetailId]
  FROM [DRILLHOLES_Export].[dbo].[DHGeochemistryAttr]
      WHERE [AttributeValue] > 1.00 and [AttributeColumn] = 'Au'
```

The Software throws the following error:

> Msg 8115, Level 16, State 8, Line 2
>   Arithmetic overflow error converting nvarchar to data type numeric.

I tried to convert to number with:

```
SELECT TOP 1000 [Id]
      ,[DHGeochemistryId]
      ,[AttributeColumn]
      ,[AttributeValue] 
      ,[ModifiedDate]
      ,[ModifiedBy]
      ,[MRTDetailId]
  FROM [DRILLHOLES_Export].[dbo].[DHGeochemistryAttr]
  SET myValue = CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(AttributeValue)=1 THEN CAST(AttributeValue AS float)
      ELSE 0 END)
      WHERE [AttributeValue]  > 1.00 and [AttributeColumn] = 'Au'
```

The Software throws the following error:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 10
>   Incorrect syntax near '='. (Line 10 is the “SET” command)

I am using SQL Server 2014 would appreciate a little help.

Comment: You can't do `SET` inside a `SELECT`.

Comment: The SET statement is not within the SELECT statement but a separate statement (unintentional I think). The combination with CASE... leads to the error. After solving that the error will go to the WHERE statement which is by itself not a valid statement.
CONVERT or CAST should make the comparison possible, but a check on the value being numeric may be required depending on the possible values off AttributeValue.

Answer (score 4):

The first statement complains because `AttributeValue` is not a numeric column. You can `CAST` it though:

```
WHERE CAST([AttributeValue] AS FLOAT)  > 1.00
```

But that might error if any of the values in there are not numeric. So you can use `ISNUMERIC` before you cast:

```
WHERE ISNUMERIC([AttributeValue]) = 1
AND CAST([AttributeValue] AS FLOAT)  > 1.00
```

SQL Server is clever enough to short circuit the logic so it won't try to `CAST` if the first part of the `WHERE` clause returns false.

Comment: #multi-lingual-problems

Comment: @Tanner The perils of polyglotism (is that a word? it should be!)

Comment: In my tests if the nvarchar is a string the cast will still fail.  I am not so sure that SQL is as clever as you had hoped.

Comment: While Sql Server is smart enough to short circuit, this takes a second in the precedence list to matching up indexes and other performance considerations, such that you'll often find your cast() running before your IsNumeric() filter.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn Interesting, is there a way to coerce the precedence then? Other than a subquery?

Answer (score 1):

I still believe it will error out, but you can put it in a try...catch and you should be fine.  Here is a sample:

```
create table #test (
    attValue nvarchar(100),
    attCol nvarchar(100))

insert into #test (attValue, attCol)
select '.99', 'Au'
union
select '1.1', 'Au'
union
select 'hello', 'Au'
union
select '1.01', 'Au'
union
select '1.2', 'Au'
union
select '1.5', 'Au'

begin try
    ;with atts (AttributeValue, AttributeCol) as
    ( 
    select convert(float, x.attValue) as aVal, x.attCol
      from (
            select attValue, attCol
              from #test
             where IsNumeric(attValue) = 1
           ) x
    )
    select * from atts
    where AttributeValue > cast(1.0 as float)
end try
begin catch
    -- do nothing
end catch
```